# Can someone help me make this PowerShell Recursive

Tags: powershell, glob

I can't seem to get this PowerShell to recurse through all directories and make the changes I need to ensure my terraform scripts can access my modules in my git repos when they apply as the build account in Azure devops.

```bsh
$InputFiles = Get-Item "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Terraform/*.tf"
$OldString  = "git::https://dev.azure.com"
$NewString  = "git::https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com"
Write-Host $NewString
$InputFiles | ForEach {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString, $NewString) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

This code works on the top-level directory but doesn't process any of the subdirectories.

I thought some kind of globbing would work i.e.

```bsh
$InputFiles = Get-Item "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Terraform/**/*.tf"
```

but no it doesn't. I'm not that strong on PowerShell and have always found it a little counterintuitive so maybe this is a simple problem for someone used to it.

Comment: What is `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`? Try `$InputFiles = Get-Item "(Get-ChildItem $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Terraform/ -Filter *.tf -Recurse)"`

Comment: @NekoMusume `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` is an Azure DevOps variable. It will be replaced with the literal string when YAML is rendered, before script runs.

Comment: This should do it. `$InputFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path  "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Terraform/" -Filter *.tf -Recurse`

Comment: Just realized the `Get-Item` in my suggestion is irrelevant, use Sage's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this script works for you:
(You can change the folder path and strings according to your need)

```
$FolderPath = "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Terraform/"
$OldString  = "git::https://dev.azure.com"
$NewString  = "git::https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com"

foreach($currentFile in Get-ChildItem -Path ($FolderPath) -Include *.tf -Recurse)
{
    If (Get-Content $currentFile.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $OldString) 
    {
        (Get-Content -path $currentFile.FullName -Raw) -replace $OldString, $NewString | Set-Content $currentFile.FullName
    }
}

Write-Information "Done"
```